# How to check for EL syntax errors in Oozie workflow?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, workflow, el, oozie

I have an Oozie workflow and have implemented a decision control node to check the values of MapReduce counters. If the values are incorrect an action of sending notification email is invoked.

Now I want to create another decision to send an email in case there are syntax errors in the EL expression itself like `${hadoop:counters("mr-action")["FirstMapper"]["Saved records"] gt 5}`. But the most challenging question that I still haven't solved and need an advice with - is how should I implement checking for syntax errors?

Here is my current decision node:

```
<decision name="check-counters">
        <switch>
            <case to="incorrect-counters-email">${hadoop:counters("mr-action")["FirstMapper"]["Saved records"] gt 5}</case>
            <default to="end"/>
        </switch>
</decision>
```